# Get scroll position of ViewCell inside ListView Xamarin Form

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.forms, coordinates, scroll-position, screen-positioning

I would like to know the scroll position of ViewCell inside the ListView.

Tried with various ways but always that gives me 0 value.

My intension is to get ViewCell's position in screen. In order to resolve this problem trying to get it's scroll position and then i will add this value to the Y value of ListView object.

Can anybody please help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make custom renderer of the ViewCell its kinda tricky to send the positions to pcl then we subscribe to the event in the view  here's my code

**PCL**

```
    public class SAChatViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public delegate int[] IntEventHandler(object sender, float[] postion);
    public event IntEventHandler OnCellItemLongClicked;
    public event EventHandler OnCellItemTouched;


    public void InvokeOnCellItemLongClicked(object sender, float[] e)
    {
        //send the current grid
        OnCellItemLongClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
    public void InvokeOnCellItemTouched(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //send the current grid
        OnCellItemTouched?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

}
```

**Android Renderer**

```
class SAChatViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        private bool selected;
        ClickListener handler = new ClickListener();
        static Android.Widget.ListView listView;
        Xamarin.Forms.ListView listviewforms;
        static SAChatViewCell cellElement;
        Android.Views.View cellControl;

        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cellControl == null)
                {
                    cellControl = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
                }

                cellElement = item as SAChatViewCell;
                selected = false;


                listviewforms = cellElement.View.Parent.Parent as Xamarin.Forms.ListView;
                if (listviewforms == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (listviewforms.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid() == Color.Transparent.ToAndroid())
                {
                    cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());
                }
                else
                {

                    cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(listviewforms.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
                }


                cellControl.SetOnLongClickListener(handler);
                cellControl.SetOnTouchListener(handler);

                return cellControl;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        { 
            base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, args);
            if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
            {
                // I had to create a property to track the selection because cellCore.Selected is always false.
                // Toggle selection
                selected = !selected;
                var selectedBackground = cellElement.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToAndroid();
                if (selected)
                {
                    if (selectedBackground == Color.Transparent.ToAndroid())
                    {
                        cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());
                        return;
                    }
                    cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(selectedBackground);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (listviewforms.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid() == Color.Transparent.ToAndroid())
                    {
                        cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        cellControl.SetBackgroundColor(listviewforms.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        internal class ClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnLongClickListener, IOnTouchListener
        {
            //event priority Touch - LongClick - Click
            //NOTE: return true to indicate that we have handled the event and it should stop here;
            public bool OnLongClick(Android.Views.View sender)
            {

                var cellItem = sender as INativeElementView;
                var viewCell = sender as Android.Views.View;

                float[] location = new float[] { 0, 0 };

                Android.Views.View parentRow = (Android.Views.View)viewCell.Parent;

                listView = (Android.Widget.ListView)parentRow.Parent;
                int position = listView.GetPositionForView(parentRow);
                var x = parentRow.Right;
                var y = (parentRow.Top - listView.DividerHeight) <= 0 ? parentRow.Bottom : parentRow.Top;

                int view_height = parentRow.Height;
                location[0] = (x / MainActivity.Current.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
                location[1] = y / MainActivity.Current.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
                //send current cell

                cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemLongClicked((cellItem.Element as ViewCell).View, location);
                listView.Scroll += ListView_Scroll;

                return true;
            }


            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                base.Dispose(disposing);
                if (listView != null)
                {
                    listView.Scroll -= ListView_Scroll;
                }
            }
            private void ListView_Scroll(object sender, Android.Widget.AbsListView.ScrollEventArgs e)
            {
                cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemTouched(cellElement.View, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            //return false if you have not handled it and/or the event should continue to any other on-click listeners.
            public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
            {
                if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
                {
                    cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemTouched(cellElement.View, EventArgs.Empty);
                    //cellCore.SetOnTouchListener(this);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS Renderer**

```
  class SAUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

    }
}
//When you scroll, your cells are created in real time. cells aren't created from scratch, instead iOS just takes a cell that has just left the screen and sends it through
class SAChatViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer, IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    UITableView TV;
    SAChatViewCell cellElement;

    public IntPtr Handle => new IntPtr();

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        try
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            TV = tv;
            var uiTapGestureRecognize = new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnClick);
            var uiLongPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(OnLongClick);
            uiLongPressGestureRecognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 0.5;
            cell.AddGestureRecognizer(uiTapGestureRecognize);
            cell.AddGestureRecognizer(uiLongPressGestureRecognizer);

            cellElement = item as SAChatViewCell;
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            if (cellElement.SelectedBackgroundColor == Color.Transparent)
            { 
                cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = cellElement.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor() ?? default(UIColor)

                };
            }

            return cell;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }



    private void OnLongClick(UILongPressGestureRecognizer arg)
    {
        //get the current touch coords based on listview 
         CGPoint coords = arg.LocationInView(TV);
        //current cell
        if (arg.State != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        { 
            var indexPath = TV.IndexPathForRowAtPoint(coords);

            CGRect Rect = TV.RectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);
            //delete the listview offset
            Rect.Offset(-TV.ContentOffset.X, -TV.ContentOffset.Y);
            var CurrentViewCell = (arg.View as UIKit.UITableViewCell).Superview;

            //Note : xamarin forms cell element  MonoTouch creates it's own internal delegate type for UIScrollView so we either override the uiviewtable or trigger the ondisappear event
            var cellItem = arg.View as INativeElementView; 
            (((cellItem.Element as ViewCell).Parent) as ListView).ItemDisappearing += (s, o) =>
            {
                cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemTouched(cellElement.View, EventArgs.Empty);
            };
            float[] location = new float[] { 0, 0 };
            location[0] = (float)Rect.X;
            var Y = Rect.Top <= 0 ? Rect.Bottom : Rect.Top;
            location[1] = (float)Y;

            cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemLongClicked((cellItem.Element as ViewCell).View, location);
        } 
    }
    private void OnClick()
    {
        cellElement.InvokeOnCellItemTouched(cellElement.View, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But I have solved without creating native renderer. I have not tried your solution , may be that can be also optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution,

Problem :

> My intension is to get ViewCell's position in screen

Solution :

> - Step 1 : Keep scrollview inside the Relative layout.
> - Step 2 : When user click on scroll view's ViewCell, save touch point (X, Y) of relative layout. In Y co-ordinate, add top position of relative layout so you will get touch point relative to whole screen.
> - Step 3 : When user click on scroll view's ViewCell, call XYZ() method.
> - Step 4 : Inside XYZ() method, do whatever functionality which required on (X, Y) co-ordinate. **(Note : put 300ms delay in doing functionality in XYZ() method, as step-2 required some time in saving 
>     touch points.)**

Comment: At present that code is not available to me but writing code to achieve above steps will get you expected X,Y co-ordinate.